# Trazer dados postgresql campo data gravado como string

Tags: postgresql

Gostaria de saber se há possibilidade de de converter esse dados na hora do `select`

Buscando esse dado, traz informações erradas:

```
select * from vendas where data_venda  between  '01/03/2016' and '16/10/2016';
```

Gostaria de saber se dá para fazer assim:

```
select * from vendas where data_venda  between  '2016-03-01' and '2016-10-16';
```

O banco que estou usando é PostgreSql e esse campo data está sendo gravado como `string`.

Comment: Funciona comandos de data, como por exemplo, BETWEEN mesmo que o campo seja uma String e não DATE? Se sim, opte pela segunda opção, formato americano, já ocorreu para mim vários problemas com o primeiro exemplo, utilizando a nossa formatação de data.

Answer (score 1):

Se o campo `data_venda` não tiver `time_zone`, você pode converter as datas que você tem em `string` para `date`, usando o `TO_DATE` e depois converter para o formato americano usando o `TO_CHAR`, assim:

```
SELECT  * FROM vendas 
  WHERE data_venda 
BETWEEN TO_CHAR(TO_DATE('01/03/2016', 'DD-MM-YYYY'), 'YYYY-MM-DD') 
    AND TO_CHAR(TO_DATE('16/10/2016', 'DD-MM-YYYY'), 'YYYY-MM-DD');
```

Caso o campo `data_venda` tenha `time_zone`, você pode fazer assim:

```
SELECT  * FROM vendas 
  WHERE TO_CHAR(data_venda, 'YYYY-MM-DD') --Convertendo para o formato americano 
BETWEEN TO_CHAR(TO_DATE('01/03/2016', 'DD-MM-YYYY'), 'YYYY-MM-DD') 
    AND TO_CHAR(TO_DATE('16/10/2016', 'DD-MM-YYYY'), 'YYYY-MM-DD');
```

### *Forma simplificada:*

**Sem `timezone`**

```
SELECT  * FROM vendas 
  WHERE data_venda
BETWEEN TO_CHAR('01/03/2016'::DATE, 'YYYY-MM-DD') 
    AND TO_CHAR('16/10/2016'::DATE, 'YYYY-MM-DD');
```

**Com `timezone`**

```
SELECT  * FROM vendas 
  WHERE TO_CHAR(data_venda, 'YYYY-MM-DD') --Convertendo para o formato americano 
BETWEEN TO_CHAR('01/03/2016'::DATE, 'YYYY-MM-DD') 
    AND TO_CHAR('16/10/2016'::DATE, 'YYYY-MM-DD');
```